# Approximate the perfect fifth

Tags: code-golf, rational-numbers, music

Starting at 1-TET, give equal temperaments that have better and better approximation of the perfect fifth(just ratio 3/2). ([OEIS sequence A060528](https://oeis.org/A060528))

The formal description of the sequence, copied from the OEIS:

> A list of equal temperaments (equal divisions of the octave) whose nearest scale steps are closer and closer approximations to the ratios of two tones of musical harmony: the perfect 4th, 4/3 and its complement the perfect 5th, 3/2.

Note that by symmetry, the perfect fourth doesn't matter.

Let's say we know that 3 is in the sequence. The frequencies in 3-TET are:

```
2^0, 2^⅓, 2^⅔
```

Where `2^⅔` is the closest *logarithmic* approximation of `3/2`.

Is 4 in the sequence? The frequencies in 4-TET are:

```
2^0, 2^¼, 2^½, 2^¾
```

Where `2^½` is the closest approximation of `3/2`. This is not better than `2^⅔`, so 4 is not in the sequence.

By similar method, we confirm that 5 is in the sequence, and so on.

When given an integer `n` as input, the output must be the first N numbers of the sequence in order. For example, when `n = 7`, the output should be:

```
1 2 3 5 7 12 29
```

**Sequence description by xnor**

The irrational constant \$ \log_2(3) \approx 1.5849625007211563\dots\$ can be approximated by a sequence of rational fractions

$$ \frac{2}{1}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{5}{3}, \frac{8}{5}, \frac{11}{7}, \frac{19}{12}, \frac{46}{29}, \dots$$

A fraction is included in the sequence if it's the new closest one by absolute distance \$ \left| \frac{p}{q} - \log_2(3)\ \right|\$, that is, closer than any  other fraction with a smaller or equal denominator.

Your goal is to output the first \$n\$ denominators in order. These are sequence [A060528](https://oeis.org/A060528) ([table](https://oeis.org/A060528/b060528.txt)). The numerators (not required) are given by [A254351](https://oeis.org/A254351) ([table](https://oeis.org/A254351/b254351.txt))

**Rules:**

1. Do not import the sequence A060528 directly.
2. The format doesn't matter as long as the numbers are distinguishable. In the example above, the output can also be:

   `[1,2,3,5,7,12,29]`
3. As this is a code-golf, the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Code Golf SE! We require that all challenges be self-contained, so a description here of the sequence would be a great help.

Comment: I'm confused by the description from OEIS. It mentions perfect 4th as well (ratio 4/3), but the challenge is about perfect 5ths (ratio 3/2). I think it also needs explanation that the sequence values are the denominators of the rational approximations.

Comment: I improved the question. Now vote for reopen, please?

Comment: I like the challenge, but I find the stuff added to the description still confusing, not knowing much about music. For instance, I don't know what 1-TET or  4-TET are, and nothing seems to show up on Google. I'll try writing an explanation of how I'd describe this sequence.

Comment: @xnor For example, 12-TET means 12-tone equal temperament.

Comment: As a small technical point, I'd suggest setting some upper bound on what input n can be given. Due to float precision issues, coded solutions might eventually become inaccurate for large n, making it hard to judge which answers are valid. I think something like n=40, the max of the OEIS table, would be reasonable.

Comment: @DannyuNDos Ah yes, the 12-tone equal temperament. That's my favourite instrument

Comment: [Temparement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_temperament) is a way to define the notes that an instrument can produce; it's not an instrument

Comment: @DannyuNDos Thanks. So the comparison is between 1/2 and log2(1.5), not between 2^(1/2) and 1.5. That should be made clearer in the text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
µ¯ßNLN/3.²<αßDˆ›D–
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//8K1wq/Dn05MTi8zLsKyPM6xw59Ey4bigLpE4oCT//83)

```
µ                      # repeat until counter == input
 ¯                     #  push the global array
  ß                    #  get the minimum (let's call it M)
   N                   #  1-based iteration count
    L                  #  range 1..N
     N/                #  divide each by N
       3.²             #  log2(3)
          <            #  -1
           α           #  absolute difference with each element of the range
            ß          #  get the minimum
             Dˆ        #  add a copy to the global array
               ›       #  is M strictly greater than this new minimum?
                D–     #  if true, print N
                       #  implicit: if true, add 1 to the counter
```

Comment: Nice answer, but all I'm wondering right now is why the while-loop has 1-based indices.. :S

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>62</s> 60 bytes

```
Denominator@NestList[Rationalize[r=Log2@3,Abs[#-r]]&,2,#-1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yU1Lz83My@xJL/IwS@1uMQns7gkOggonZ@XmJNZlRpdZOuTn27kYKzjmFQcraxbFBurpmOko6xrGKv2P6AoM6/EIc3BxOA/AA)

Comment: How many precision?

Comment: @DannyuNDos This function uses exact values, so computations can be done to arbitrary precision.

Comment: You win the challenge.

Comment: @DannyuNDos why accept an answer this quickly? It's also arguably better not to accept an answer at all..

Comment: Regarding the floating-point errors other languages are suffering, I'd like to present an alternative method of alloting score. So hold on.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>81</s> <s>80</s> 78 bytes

-2 bytes thanks Arnauld!

```javascript
n=>{for(d=g=1;w=Math.log2(3),w+=~(w*g-.5)/g,n--;g++)w*w<d?d=print(g)||w*w:n++}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchRDoIwDADQ67SUIUJMjFg5gYdYWFYxZpCx0A@Bq0/f53vb1S5DHOdk1mv2nAM/vn6K4Fj43Ck/bXpVn0kaaLFU4gO0EFNd8CRlMKYTItRC7653PMcxJBDctv/cAtGePTQ15h8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 92 bytes

```python
E=k=input()
n=0
while k:
 n+=1;e=abs((3.169925001442312*n-1)%2-1)/n
 if e<E:print n;E=e;k-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcRBCoMwEADAe16xl0K0WLOrFTTuMQ@xkGKIbINGSl@fOodJv7x@hEpxHDlIOrOulLBR3zVsHuKkQO6M1vPyOrTuHjiMIz2Nwb6nDqmWBqsbXbWiILzBz25Ke5AMYh17GxvGUtD8AQ)

Uses the constant `3.169925001442312` for \$2 \log_2(3)\$. I wasn't sure how many digits of accuracy are required, since the inaccuracy will break the sequence eventually, so I used the full float precision of `2 * numpy.log2(3)`.

Comment: This gives two extra terms after 665: `..., 665, (1995), (4655), 8286, ...` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcRBCoMwEADAe16xFyEq1uyqLZruMQ9pIWKIrKFNKX197Bwm/fJ2CJXiOHKQ9Mm6VsJGfbewe4iLAmkZrefH8631cMHrPNNkDI4jDUiNdFhX9K8XBWEFf3dLegXJINaxt7FjLAVvJw "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Οurous Yeah, that's pretty much inevitable sooner or later for any language without infinite precision, though I'm surprised it popped up so early with 32-bit floats as Python uses. I'll wait for the challenge writer to clarify on how far answers need to work.

Comment: wouldn't it be fewer characters to use `2 * numpy.log2(3)` rather than the fully spelled out number? (Or even better, `numpy.log2(9)`)

Comment: @JDL that would require this code: `from numpy import*` and `log2(9)`.

Comment: ah, that is what I get for assuming python works like R and you can write `package::function` without loading `package` first!

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>128</s> <s>111</s> 108 bytes

```
import StdEnv
c=ln 3.0/ln 2.0
?d=abs(toReal(toInt(c*d))/d-c)
$i=take i(iterate(\d=until((>)(?d)o?)inc d)1.0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc29DoIwEADgnafowNCaAPVnrSw6kDjJ6nL2qrnYXg0cJr68lekbPx8DcEkZlxhUAuJC6Z0nUaPgmT@Vd5HVvrXdyq61VY8O7rOWfA0QVwYW7TdoTIeNN1VNTuAVFGmSMIEEfUO3sFDU@mh0jyb3htgrNNvWmjIKrJdTtTrY8vOPCM@5NMOlnL4Mifz8Bw)

Should work up to the limits of `Real`'s 64-bit double precision type.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-MPOSIX=log2 -M5.01 -n`), <s>73</s>, <s>78</s>, 71 bytes

Fixed following comment, may be improved...

-7 bytes thanks to Grimy

```perl
$o=abs$d-(0|.5+($d=log2 3)*++$;)/$;;$@=$o,$_-=say$;if!$@|$o<$@;$_&&redo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3zYxqVglRVfDoEbPVFtDJcU2Jz/dSMFYU0tbW8VaU1/F2lrFwVYlX0clXte2OLFSxTozTVHFoUYl30bFwVolXk2tKDUl//9/83/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9A/yDPSPA5gA5pnoGhv918wA)

Comment: [here's 71](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3zYxqVglRVfDoEbPVFtDJcU2Jz/dSMFYU0tbW8VaU1/F2lrFwVYlX0clXte2OLFSxTozTVHFoUYl30bFwVolXk2tKDUl//9/83/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9A/yDPSPA5gA5pnoGhv918wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
1`@:@/Q3Zl-|X<hY<tdzG-}df
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zDBwcpBP9A4Kke3JsImI9KmJKXKXbc2Je3/f3MA)

#### Explanation

```
1       % Push 1. This initiallizes the vector of distances
  `     % Do...while
  @:    %   Range [1, 2, ..., k], where k is the iteration index, staring at 1
  @/    %   Divide by k, element-wise. Gives [1/k, 2/k, ..., 1]
  Q     %   Add 1, element-wise. Gives [(k+1/k, (k+2)/k, ..., 2]
  3Zl   %   Push log2(3)
  -|    %   Absolute difference, element-wise
  X<    %   Minimum
  h     %   Concatenate with vector of previous distances
  Y<    %   Cumulative minimum
  t     %   Duplicate
  dz    %   Consecutive differences, number of nonzeros. This tells how many
        %   times the cumulative minimum has decreased
  G-    %   Subtract input n. This is the loop condition. 0 means we are done
}       % Finally (execute on loop exit)
  d     %   Consecutive differences (of the vector of cumulative differences)
  f     %   Indices of nonzeros. This is the final result
        % End. A new iteration is executed if the top of the stack is nonzero
        % Implicit display
```